# Search Date (now) in Specific time

Tags: mysql

I want to search a Date (now) like `2022-04-11` in specific time like `00:00:00`. and in this code showing date & time `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
SELECT Process_Date, Product_Number, COUNT(*) AS TEST FROM tb_main WHERE Process_Date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00:00:00') GROUP BY Product_Number;
```

I have already tried this code but syntax was error.

```
CURDATE(), '00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `DATE_FORMAT` to get midnight of the current date, then you need a format mask for the entire timestamp:

```sql
SELECT Process_Date, Product_Number, COUNT(*) AS TEST
FROM tb_main
WHERE Process_Date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
GROUP BY Product_Number;
```

You could also use the `TIMESTAMP` function here:

```sql
SELECT Process_Date, Product_Number, COUNT(*) AS TEST
FROM tb_main
WHERE Process_Date = TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY Product_Number;
```